# Watch recursive directories in go-inotify

Tags: linux, go, inotify

I am using this go library https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/exp/inotify for file and folder watcher in Linux inotify when we use directly in Linux it gives one parameter to be passed to watch recursive directories i.e. --r but in this wrapper how do I specify while calling the function.

```
package main

import (
"golang.org/x/exp/inotify"
"log"
)

func main() {
  watcher, err := inotify.NewWatcher()
  if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
  }
  err = watcher.Watch("/home/minions")
  if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
  }
  for {
      select {
      case ev := <-watcher.Event:
          log.Println("event:", ev)
      case err := <-watcher.Error:
          log.Println("error:", err)
      }
  }
}
```

This is my go code.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  INotify is not recursive, so you must list all the subdirectories (taking care to watch for the creation of new ones!) and add new watches as needed.

A competing library has an open ticket for recursive directory watching, but it isn't resolved as of 2016: https://github.com/howeyc/fsnotify/issues/56

Comment: But I am not using this package as I mentioned in my question I am using  this https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/exp/inotify and from this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164794/why-doesnt-inotifywatch-detect-changes-on-added-files I found that atleast inotifywatch has that recursive option.

Comment: @ShilpiAgrawal: Yes, I know.  My answer still stands.  Please read it again.  Just because some other program has a recursive option does not mean your library does.

Comment: I understand that @JohnZwinck but I was asking this question because the library I am using it just a wrapper for that program So, I thought may they have it. Anyways no issues, I am thinking to user python's watchddog instead.

Comment: @ShilpiAgrawal: The library you are using in Go is a wrapper for the C library for INotify, not the program that supports recursive.  The Go library does not invoke a separate program, it just calls the C library which does not itself support recursive watches.

Comment: Deep down in the source of gohugo.io, is a recursive watch if you want to dig it out.  I suspect he just transverses all directories and issues a watch across all.  With the channel <- supplied, you  could create a a collection of Go routines that all watch a single directory as you transverse them.  All that the go routines have to do is watch, and send a single bit flag on another cha nel, to trigger another rebuild.